# Django reset password email signed using DomainKey with Amazon SES

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, dkim

The application I am trying to experiment allows users to reset their password using djangos inbuilt `PasswordResetForm` , currently I am overriding it to be able to send HTML emails using `EmailMultiAlternatives`.

How it currently looks and works fine.

```
c ={'name':'Shabeer'}
subject = 'Test Amazon SES'
txt_content = loader.render_to_string('registration/password_reset_email.txt', c)
html_content = loader.render_to_string(email_template_name, c)

msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, txt_content, from_email, [user.email]);            
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, 'text/html')
msg.send()
```

So now I started with the help of this [`Getting started`](https://github.com/hmarr/django-ses#getting-going) example by *hmarr*,here is the code I added to my `settings.py`

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_ses.SESBackend'

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'shabeer@sheffa.com'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'MyAcCeSsKeYiD'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'MySeCrEtAcCeSsKeY'
AWS_SES_REGION_NAME = 'us-east-1'
AWS_SES_REGION_ENDPOINT = 'email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
AWS_SES_RETURN_PATH = 'shabeer@sheffa.com'
```

And the emails get successfully sent to users via amazon SES.

**So now here is my problem**.

I am trying to avoid  seeing [`"via" followed by a domain name next to the sender's name`](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1311182?hl=en).

To achieve that I started to follow the next step [`DKIM`](https://github.com/hmarr/django-ses#dkim) of the guide. :

1. Added the DKIM settings for my domain that was generated by Amazon SES
2. Added the following to `settings.py`

> DKIM_DOMAIN = 'myDomainName.com'`

2. Downloaded [openssl-for windows](https://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/detail?name=openssl-0.9.8k_X64.zip) , and followed the commands

   > - openssl genrsa -out myDomainName.com.key 512
   > - openssl rsa -in myDomainName.com.key -out rsa.public -pubout -outform PEM
   >     
   >     Two files got created : **myDomainName.com.key** and **rsa.public**
3. Added the DKIM_PRIVATE_KEY to `settings.py`

   > DKIM_PRIVATE_KEY = '''
   >   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
   >   MY Long Private Key
   >   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
   >   '''
4. Added the DNS Entry

   > ses._domainkey.myDomainName.com TXT '"v=DKIM1; p=myPublicKey"'

With all the above done, I run my project and try to reset my password, and this error gets thrown :

```
Exception Type: KeyFormatError at /password_reset/
Exception Value: Private key not found
```

I trying to understand what I have missed or gone wrong, some advice/assistance on how I could solve this would be really help full.

I am a rookie at Django/Python so please bear with me.

Thanks you in advance.

> **UPDATE 28 Oct 2013:**

I am still trying to figure out which **`Private Key`** django is looking for while I have already added **`DKIM_PRIVATE_KEY`** in my `settings.py`

> **UPDATE 29 Oct 2013:**

- With the help of [Paul Egan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590543/django-reset-password-email-signed-using-domainkey-with-amazon-ses/19654903?noredirect=1#19654903) I  updated my **`DKIM_PRIVATE_KEY`**
  in my `settings.py` to include `PEM header` looks like this now :

  `DKIM_PRIVATE_KEY = '''

  -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

  -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
  '''`

The emails get sent now without any errors, **but** the email I receive still shows `via amazonses.com`

Comment: Guys any idea on how to overcome this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Private key not found` error is thrown from [parse_pem_private_key](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~dkimpy-hackers/dkimpy/trunk/view/head:/dkim/crypto.py#L147). This suggests that your setting doesn't include the PEM headers. Double check that it looks something like:

```
DKIM_PRIVATE_KEY = '''
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
xxxxxxxxxxx
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
'''
```

There's another option you might also want to consider. Last year AWS added support for adding the DKIM signature on their side: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/easy-dkim.html. You might find this easier to configure and it has the added advantage of keeping the private key away from your source code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I added the PEM header and the email gets sent without errors, but it still shows `via amazonses.com`. And I did configure the `Easy DKIM` it hides `via amazonses.com` only when I send a  test email. Nothing happens when sent via django.

Comment: Check the headers in the email that you have received, in particular `DKIM-Signature`. It should indicate what might have gone wrong - perhaps a mismatch with the key published via DNS. (On the Gmail web client use the "More" menu and select "Show original").

Comment: If using the "easy" DKIM option on SES you don't need to specify any DKIM config for Django. The signature will be applied after the message is send from Django to SES. Check that DKIM Signing is enabled for the email address you're using as the sender in Django (or enabled for the entire domain) and that the status is "verified".

Comment: Although my Domain was verified, the email address I was using to send emails was not verified, the email was using a different domain. Thank you for bringing it to my attention. Since the domain was configured with `Easy DKIM` I removed the `DKIM` settings from `settings.py`. Works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: I have to wait 20hrs to award you the bounty, so hang in there mate :)